# JS to invoke a java method which inturn calls a Database

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, tomcat

I need some help on solving the following:Write a JS to invoke a Java method which in turn calls a database. Host the application on tomcat. Use mysql as the database.

I wrote down a sample code in java and accessed a sample database from MySql, now- How can I access this from a JS.

Comment: Have you created web services before?

Comment: I haven't used web service before. I created a sample table in mySql invoked the data through a java class. I also installed the tomcat plug-in into my Eclipse. Now, i need help on how to invoke the java method through a JS!

Answer (score 0):

My assumption here is that you are talking about client side java script and not server side java script. You are trying to implement a standard client-server use case. Here your java script code is client and your java code is server. Since your client side code will be running inside a browser most likely so your best best will be to expose your java method invokable over http protocol. For this you will need to host your Java application as a web-application using servers like [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/), [JBoss](http://www.jboss.org/) etc. You can search about how to implement this on Google.
You can begin with following links:

- http://helloworldprograms.blogspot.com/2010/08/servlet-hello-world.html
- http://crunchify.com/create-and-deploy-simple-web-service-and-web-service-client-in-eclipse/